# App crashes when using putExtra in startActivity(intent) called from ViewHolder of RecyclerView inside Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am struggling with this problem: the activity should start but it doesn't when using putExtra. The only thing that happens is that I see the Fragment sliding on the right (after a glitch) and then the app crashes. Note that this Fragment is part of the Navigation component. Here is my code, inside onClick method:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ID", ID);

v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
Log.w("here", "should have started");
```

where "v" is the View of the RecyclerView that I clicked. This is what appears on the Logcat soon after the click:

```
V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
W/here: should have started
V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 7695
W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@b33fd52
V/FA: Connecting to remote service
V/FA: Activity paused, time: 295957791
```

When I reopen the application, it restarts from the MainActivity (the beginning). SecondActivity starts if I comment the putExtra line, which is a very strange behavior imo. Any help will be appreciated! :)

Comment: you need to post the logcat of the stack trace, this info isn't useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provide Activity Context to start Activity.
Starting an activity from ViewHolder is not the good practice, as it is violation of Single Responsibility Principle.
Implement delegation pattern to handle Click Listener in ViewHolder.

```
interface ItemClickListener {
   void onClick(YourModel item);
}
```

Your Adapter

```
    class YourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<YourViewHolder>{
     ItemClickListener listener;
      public YourAdapter(ItemClickListener listener){
      this.listener = listener;
     }
}
```

Usage of listener

```
listener.onClick(position);
```

Your Activity

```
YourAdapter adapter = YourAdapter(item -> {
   // handle click
})
```

Comment: this answer is perfect, it's just worth saying that you don't have to _just_ pass back the position of the item clicked, you can pass back the actual model of the item at the specific position which was clicked (as it's available when binding the specific view holder) meaning that it could also be `onClick(X data)` where X is any datatype

Comment: thanks for correcting my mistake. I have updated my answer